# Finding SQL duplicates - two methods different results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in which duplicates may appear. A duplicate is considered when:
sector_id, department_id,number_id are the same (I will add that these are foreign keys to other tables, because maybe it is important)
and valid_to is null

I did this with two queries:

1.

```
select count(*) from(
select sector_id, departament_id,numer_id, count(*) from tables.workspace 
where valid_to is null
group by 1,2,3
having count(*) >1 ) as r

--results : 650
```

2. 

```
with duplicate_rows as
(
select *, count(id) over (partition by sector_id, departament_id, numer_id) duplicate_count from tables.workspace where valid_to is null
)

select count(*) from
(
select * from duplicate_rows where duplicate_count >1
) as t
--results : 3655
```

Please explain what I`m doing wrong, possibly why these two functions return different values and which of them is true

Answer (score 0):

Your second query is the wrong one.

You're using a window function and selecting everything in your CTE, which means that every record will have the total `COUNT` for each combination of your `partition by` fields.

For example, if there are 3 records with `sector_id = 'A', departament_id = 'RED', numer_id = 1`, your CTE will look like this:

```
  sector_id | departament_id | numer_id | duplicate_count
------------+----------------+----------+-----------------
  A         | RED            |        1 |               3
  A         | RED            |        1 |               3
  A         | RED            |        1 |               3
```

Which means that your second query will return 3 instead of 1.

Try adding a `DISTINCT` to the query that selects from the CTE and it should give you the same results as your first query.

```
select distinct * from duplicate_rows where duplicate_count >1
```